# Is it possible to change how Update Manager displays the updates?

Tags: fonts, update-manager, updates

Is it possible to change the way how Update Manager displays the updates currently available?
Currently (in Maverick 10.10) the packages are shown with their description in a larger font, and their package name (and size) in smaller font.

I would prefer having the other way round: read easily what's the package name in question, and if I don't recognize what is it, read in smaller text what that package does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can:

1) alt+f2 and gconf-editor

2) Edit → Find: update-manager

Then changes sone option e.g. show_details, show_version,

Comment: Thanks! The solution was to use gconf-editor and in /apps/update-manager disable the item 'summary_before_name'.